# How to prove main argument formula for any $z\in\mathbb C^*$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I would prove that for any complex number $z \in \mathbb C^*$ such that $z = x + \mathbb i y$ with $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ and $x+\vert z\vert \neq 0$:
$$ \arg z = 2\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+\vert z\vert}\right)$$
How to begin a proof of this formula?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation is, of course, that $x+|z|\ne0$, that is, the formula doesn't hold for $x<0$ and $y=0$. Other than this case, we have
$$
-\pi<2\arctan\frac{y}{x+|z|}<\pi
$$
so the angle is in the required interval.

If $\alpha=2\arctan t$, then
$$
\cos\alpha=\cos(2\arctan t)=2\cos^2\arctan t-1=
\frac{2}{1+t^2}-1=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}
$$
and
$$
\sin\alpha=\sin(2\arctan t)=2\tan\arctan t\cos^2\arctan t=
\frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$
Now, if $t=y/(x+|z|)$, we have
$$
1+t^2=1+\frac{y^2}{x^2+2x|z|+|z|^2}=\frac{2|z|(x+|z|)}{(x+|z|)^2}
=\frac{2|z|}{x+|z|}
$$
whereas
$$
1-t^2=1-\frac{y^2}{x^2+2x|z|+|z|^2}=\frac{2x}{x+|z|}
$$
so that
$$
\cos\alpha=\frac{x}{|z|}
$$
and, similarly,
$$
\sin\alpha=\frac{y}{|z|}
$$
so
$$
|z|(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)=x+iy
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's possible to prove it without knowing of the "formula" for angle $\alpha = 2\arctan \left(\dfrac{y}{x+\vert z\vert}\right)$? Else thanks :)

Comment: @SuperFoxy I'm not sure what you mean; perhaps how to go directly from the trigonometric representation to the formula?

Comment: Yes, a way to go directly to the formula...

Answer (score 1):

for $x>0,y>0, z = x+iy$ :  $$\text{arg}(z) = \text{atan}(y/x)$$

with $s = x+ |z|+iy$ you get $$\text{arg}(s) = \text{atan}\left(\frac{y}{x+|z|}\right)$$ but $$s^2 = (x+ |z|)^2-y^2+2iy(x+ |z|)=2(x+ |z|)(x+iy) = 2(x+ |z|) z$$
so that
$$\text{arg}(z) = \text{arg}(s^2)  = 2 \text{arg}(s)$$

I let you treat the other cases ($x \le 0$ or $y \le 0$)